# React-Native : Firebase Realtime Database How Can I Get One Data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database.
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONTBv.png)

How can i get firstName in React-Native ?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 2):

It's simple in your case : use react-native-firebase

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'


 const ref = firebase.database().ref('users/fwDRY...G3');
 const name = ref.get({ firstname: 'firstname' });
 console.log(name.firstname)
```

*Find yourself helpful from the docs: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/database/reference/database*

Comment: How can i use this in view ?

Comment: use state to store the name and use inside the <Text> block.
eg:
 this.setState({firstname: name.firstname)}  \\-> replace console.log line with this;
<View>
  <Text>
    {this.state.firstname}
 </Text>
<View>

Answer (score 1):

As React Native runs in Java Script thread on mobile platforms there are 2 ways to use it.

1. Using Web SDK, but it might be slower and is not as well integrated to the mobile operating system as native.
2. Using Native SDK for each platform. Using them manually on 2 platforms would require you to write React Native bindings for both platforms. Fortunately, the job has already been done. I highly recommend you to use this library https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase. It uses native APIs internally but exposes them into nice JavaScript API. It requires some setup but you won't work it around anyway regardless of the method chosen.
   For example, to set it up for Android, you need to follow

   - https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup
   - https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android
   - https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/database/android

After you set it up, follow the link provided by frank-van-puffelen, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events. The API on react-native-firebase is almost the same.